# Considerações probabilísticas sobre o Cálculo da Entropia de Shannon em um tráfego de rede

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, matemática

Considerações probabilísticas sobre o Cálculo da Entropia de Shannon em um tráfego de rede

Tenho um arquivo dump (formato CAP) de uma captura de tráfego de rede feita com o tcpdump do Debian. Até certo horário, é um tráfego livre de ataques. Depois, começam uma série de ataques do tipo TCP SYN flooding. Meu objetivo é calcular a entropia de cada um dos momentos do tráfego (com e sem ataques) e compará-los.

Estou usando o código Python:

```
import numpy as np
import collections

sample_ips = [
    "131.084.001.031",
    "131.084.001.031",
    "131.284.001.031",
    "131.284.001.031",
    "131.284.001.000",
]

C = collections.Counter(sample_ips)
counts = np.array(list(C.values()),dtype=float)
#counts  = np.array(C.values(),dtype=float)
prob    = counts/counts.sum()
shannon_entropy = (-prob*np.log2(prob)).sum()
print (shannon_entropy)
```

Ao fazer o cálculo desta maneira, surgem algumas dúvidas:

1. Estou considerando uma distribuição de probabilidades discreta e com espaço amostral equiprovável. Isto é razoável?
   Como justificar isto? Eu não sei como é a distribuição...

2.Como validar o experimento? Estou pensando em um teste de hipóteses com a seguinte hipótese nula:
"O valor da entropia permite detectar o ataque" Está coerente? Qual seria um bom teste de hipóteses para o caso (o espaço amostral tem tamanho por volta de 40)

Comment: Quando você diz que o espaço amostral tem tamanho por volta de 40 você está dizendo que possui ~40 arquivos .CAP que contém um ataque em algum momento?

Answer (score 2):

1) Se você conseguir chegar a mesma conclusão para as distribuições de probabilidades em amostragens com diferentes intervalos de tempo em diferentes dias sua resposta é sim.

2) um experimento deve ser elaborado/pensado em como será feito, depois deve ser descrito em papel em cada passo dele, sem pular nenhuma etapa, ele deve ser possível de ser refeito por outra pessoa que duvidar dos dados obtidos. Depois de escrito deve ser feito, repetidas vezes com dados diferentes, e todos devem chegar a mesma conclusão.

Voce pode ler mais sobre [Metodologia Cientifica](https://guiadamonografia.com.br/metodologia-cientifica/), vai te ajudar.

Comment: :" Se você conseguir dados idênticos de distribuição de probabilidades para diferentes intervalos de tempo em diferentes dias sua resposta é sim." Nao entendi

Comment: vou editar, isso ficou errado